# Margin auto not being respected despite using display block

Tags: html, css, label, margin, display

I have a `div` containing two `label` elements. Each `label` should be on a side of the `div`. As labels are inline elements, I have tried with `display: block` and also with `display: inline-block` for margins to take effect, but the result is not the expected one.

```css
  div {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
  }
  label:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  label:nth-of-type(2) {
    display: block;
    <!-- display: inline-block; -->
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Left side label</label>
  <label>right side label</label>
</div>
```

As you can see with the code execution, the second label is not respecting the margins and is being displayed underneath the first one.

Comment: are you trying to position both labels on the same level, whereas the left label is one the left side and the right label is on right?

Comment: If you would like them to be on the same line but different sides they will need to be inline or inline-block. If you insist on using margin the one which receives margin auto will probably need to have the width set so the auto setting knows how far to move it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The label must have a width and display:block to work with margin auto.

Today it's more flexibel to use flexbox for this.

```css
div {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

label:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

label:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Left side label</label>
      <label>right side label</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With more modern methods like CSS Grid or Flexbox, this can be accomplished. But my solution will be with raw CSS to keep at a similar level to OP's code.

Both labels will need to have `display: inline-block` applied to get both elements to be treated like block elements and remain on the same line. You'll also need to set a `width` to give them a container to work with when adjusting the text placement. For this example, we'll do `width: 50%`.

**Note:** `inline-block` elements that take up a full `width: 100%` will result in the labels being on separate lines **unless** you modify the html to remove the whitespace in between the elements. Read more why on this behavior [here](https://uxengineer.com/inline-block-elements-100-percent-width/) and a personal [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/nz2w0q8z4) of fixing this.

You'll notice I also removed `margin-left` and `margin-right` from the width calculation and instead used `padding` to result in the same spacing on the left and right.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
      <!-- Remove whitespace between labels to not exceed width: 100% -->
      <label>Left side label</label><label>right side label</label>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

label:nth-of-type(1) {
  text-align: left; /* Not necessary, but you can explicitly set the behavior you want. */
}

label:nth-of-type(2) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJRMQx)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to specify the display property, just let it be inline and play around with the float property to float them.

```css
<style>
div {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  
}

label:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left;
}

label:nth-of-type(2) {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <label>Left side label</label>
    <label>right side label</label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```